# Replacing an Awk statment with Findstr

Tags: windows, awk, findstr

I am trying to figure out how to utilize findstr so that it will do the same thing as this line in awk:

```
wk.exe "begin {temp=0}/^stringMarker/{temp=1}{if (temp==1)print$0}" %TEMP%\input.txt >%TEMP%\output.txt
```

This is all I can think of right now:

```
@ECHO OFF
findstr /b /c:"Hello" Hello.bat > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Search Failed
) else (
echo Search Sucessful
)
```

as you can see the latter half of the code is missing. I need help to find out how to get the lines after the stringMarker and then be able to redirect them into a file.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think `findstr` has such functionality.  With `grep` you could say `grep -A1234567 ^stringMarker input.txt` and get all the subsequent lines as trailing context (assuming the file is smaller than the insanely big number) but that, too, is only a crude approximation.  Why do you not want to use `awk`, which does this succintly and elegantly?

Comment: The `awk` script is a bit cumbersome, you could try `"/^stringMarker/{print}"` which does the same thing.

Comment: That would only print lines that matched. The original script prints all lines from the match to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a windows port of gawk if possible.  If you can't for some reason, maybe a vbscript would work best?

If you must use findstr and cmd, the following should work.

`find_thing.cmd "^stringMarket" in.txt > out.txt`

**find_thing.cmd**

```
@echo off

if "%~1"=="" ((echo no arguments) && exit /b)
if "%~2"=="" ((echo insufficient arguments) && exit /b)

set query=%~1
set file_name=%~2

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /r /n "%query%" "%file_name%"') do (
    echo %%b
    more +%%a "%file_name%"
    exit /b
)
```